# Ecuador Census Data

Tags: data, census, administrative-boundaries, ecuador

I am looking for Ecuador census data (digital GIS if possible) at the sub-parroquia (parish) level.

The geographies and the tabular data would be great but at this point I am mostly in need of the digital boundaries.

I am looking for the full demographic suite of data with attributes if possible.

2010 would be great but I am also interested in 2001 and 1990.

Any digital GIS format will suffice for the boundaries and any tabular format for the tabular data.

Non-free options are fine as well.

The geographies are known as Sector and Zona (Zone) in the Ecuadorian Census.

Comment: The geographies are known as Sector and Zona (Zone) in the Ecuadorian Census.

Comment: I have seen it used in certain academic papers.

Answer (score 4):

check this link http://www.geohive.com/cntry/ecuador.aspx  for the census data (1990,2001 and 2010)

this one http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/metadata.show?id=1174&currTab=simple for the admin limits

By the way it is better to add the info that you are looking for the admin regions called "Parishes". These are third-level administrative units of Ecuador (also known as municipalities in other countries).

Comment: Thanks for the two links. I am aware of both. Geohive only has population counts at the Canton level which is one above Parroquia (which means Parish) and I already have the Parroquia and Canton tabular data. I am looking for sub-Parroquia (smaller than) Additionally, I am looking for the full demographic suite such as age, poverty, household size, etc., at the sub-Parroquia level and not just counts. I already have these data at the Parroquia level. The FAO is also Canton and not sub-Parroquia. Can you expand on why is it better to use the Parroquia (Parishes) universally? Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

In Ecuador you should contact the INEC http://www.inec.gob.ec/ that is the institution directly related with the information you are looking for.

In this site you can find  data from the last census but also from the past census in different level of details. If you are not able to find what are you looking for in the site you can contact one representative of INEC to help you in your search.